# ¿Como exigir una cantidad especifica de caracteres en un campo?

Tags: php, html

Quiero que cierto campo en especifico solo pueda tener 16 caracteres, no mas, ni menos, estoy usando php.

Comment: Hola, agrega mas información y el código que has intentado para mejorar la calidad de la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ciertoCampo = $_POST['cierto-campo']; 
// Supongo que al ser un dato de 16 caracteres necesitarás POST
if (strlen($ciertoCampo) == 16) {
      // Lo que tengas que hacer con los datos recibidos
} else {
      // Algún mensaje indicando que son necesarios 16 caracteres exactamente
}
```

Comment: Gracias capo ! Super util, no tenia idea !!

Comment: De nada, espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Las validaciones empiezan en el lado del cliente y se terminan en el lado del servidor.
Lo primero por la comodidad del usuario y lo segundo por seguridad (nunca confíes en el lado del cliente).

**Cliente**

Si asumimos que tu cliente es html+css+js la alternativa mas sencilla son los atributos **minlength** y **maxlength** del input (siempre que sea text, email, search, password, tel, o url):

```
<iput name="mi-input" id="mi-input" type="text" minlength="16" maxlength="16">
```

la ventaja de esto es que si el input es enviado usando el evento submit del formulario al que pertenece (y si el browser es relativamente moderno) el formulario no se enviará y se mostrara un tooltip en el input

**y en el Servidor**

```
$miInput = $_REQUEST["mi-input"]; /* cambiar $_REQUEST por el metodo apropiado ($_GET o $_POST) */
if( strlen($miInput) != 16 ){
 /* actuar en consecuencia */
}
```

**Otras alternativas del cliente**

De manera ilustrativa tambien podrías agregar un listener al evento submit (si el campo esta en un formulario) y verificar el tamaño antes de enviar:

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="mi-formulario">
 <input name="mi-input" id="mi-input" type="text" minlength="16" maxlength="16">
 <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
 <script>     
   document.getElementById("mi-formulario").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var miInput = document.getElementById("mi-input").value;
       if( miInput.length != 16 ){
           /*
           actuar en consecuencia, mostrar un mensaje u otra acción
           */
       }
    })
 </script>
```

Si por alguna razón el formulario no se envia usando un evento submit una alternativa sencilla es agregar un listener al botón o al elemento que inicia el envio del formulario:

```
    <form method="POST" action="" id="mi-formulario">
     <input name="mi-input" id="mi-input" type="text" minlength="16" maxlength="16">
     <button type="button" id="mi-boton">OK</button>
   </form>
   <script>     
     document.getElementById("mi-boton").addEventListener("click", function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var miInput = document.getElementById("mi-input").value;
       if( miInput.length != 16 ){
           /*
           actuar en consecuencia, mostrar un mensaje u otra acción
           */
       }
    })
 </script>
```

Recuerda siempre validar tus formularios en el lado del servidor, en el lado del cliente es relativamente sencillo alterar el código para ingresar más caracteres en el campo.

algunos enlaces de interés:

- [Validación proporcionada por el browser en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Validacion_formulario_datos)
- [elemento input en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input)
- [strlen en el manual de php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strlen.php)
- [validación de inputs (en ingles)](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Input-Validation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Lo podrias hacer del lado del cliente con JavaScript

```
if(campo.length == 16){
 /*Acción que se vaya a realizar cuando sea valido*/ 
}else{
  alert("El campo debe de tener 16 caracteres.");
}
```